# Why does my RCCB keeps tripping every time I want to start a 3-phase motor?

Tags: motor, grounding, leakage-current

I am working on a filtration pump using a simple start-stop button for the 3 phase motor Electrical diagram is attached below. Most of the main components are from Schneider. The "Pump Run" pilot lamp is 220V AC. The 3-phase motor is 1.1kW with 6 pole. All push buttons are momentary (not locking).

[image: ELectrical diagram]

So we are required to use a RCCB, but there's no "neutral" in the supply line (only R-S-T & ground). I searched and found that Schneider RCCB type A9R71425 can be used without connecting the neutral pole, so we tried to use that. When we press the "Pump Start" button, the motor runs for a brief second & the RCCB suddenly trips.

We tried to disconnect the motor (so using only the contactor & thermal overload relay) & press the "start" button again, but the result is the same.

Are there any errors/something that shouldn't have been connected in the electrical diagram?

Comment: Is the RCCB one with overcurrent protection? If so, perhaps the start current for the motor exceeds that and makes it trip? Also, even of the neutral is not connected on the consumption side, you should probably connect it on the supply side rather than leave it floating...(?)

Comment: Kelvin Galiny - Hi, You posted an answer to say thank you. Although that's appreciated, Stack Exchange has different rules from typical forums (please see the [tour] & [help]). An *answer* cannot be used in that way, so it was deleted, sorry. Please see the article in the [help] called: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](/help/someone-answers)" & follow that guidance. If your question has been solved, consider upvoting useful answers & [áccepting](/help/accepted-answer) your choice of best answer. Or if you need clarification on an answer, you can comment below it. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

> *Why does my RCCB keeps tripping every time I want to start a 3-phase
> motor?*

An RCCB is a residual current circuit breaker (also known as an RCD or GFCI) and, the problem is that you are using protective earth (PE) to power a lamp (pump run) and your "hour meter".

[image]

The small load currents these take are probably enough to trip the RCCB. Instead of using PE (protective earth) connect to neutral.

Of course there may be other reasons but these stick out immediately.

Answer (score 5):

All current that goes out through a RCD must return through the same RCD.

As andy-aka says you are abusing the PE connection as a Neutral for your hour meter and pump run lamp. Since this path does not go through the RCD, the RCD sees it as leakage current.

Possible fixes.

1. Run a proper neutral connection from the supply to the panel, through the RCD and to the hour meter and pump run light.
2. Replace the hour meter and pump run light with 400V versions and connect them phase to phase.
3. Install a step down transformer to provide an accessory supply from the 400V supply for the indicator and meter.

Technically you could continue to abuse the ground as neutral by routing the return currents from the hour meter and indicator to the earth bar via the neutral pole of the RCD, but you are almost certainly not supposed to do that.

Comment: You are 100% not supposed to connect earth through neutral terminal of RCD. If you do this then RCD is useless and would never trip.

Comment: You certainly shouldn't route actual earthing connections through the RCD. That was not what I said.

Comment: "not supposed to do that" You would lose RCD protection for the hour meter and indicator lamp so don't do that. The other measures you suggest should work.